# Mathematics Graduate Student Summer Opportunities

Tags: mathematics-education

I am currently a mathematics graduate student at Western Kentucky University in Bowling Green, KY. I am looking for some kind of summer opportunity to participate in during summer 2011.

Does anyone have any suggestions of good opportunities or a good list of opportunities?

I would really appreciate it!

EDIT: I am more interested in pure mathematics than I am in applied mathematics. My favorite areas are set theory, complex variables/analysis, topology, difference equations, difference(discrete) calculus, and time scale calculus.

I am really looking to broaden my horizons though with new and interesting topics.

Naturally, I am going to speak with my advisor and professors, but I would like to get insight from others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSA has a summer program. Should be somewhere at http://www.nsa.gov

Answer (score 3):

One of the first place to check would be, of course, the AMS website.

http://ams.org/programs/students/gradinfo/gradinfo

which also links to

http://orion.math.iastate.edu/dept/GraduateOpportunities.html

Though you need to be a bit more precise about what you mean by opportunity. Do you mean summer school? Internships? Teaching fellowships? Mentoring opportunities (where you teach some summer courses for undergraduates or advanced high-schoolers)?

And... if you are a graduate student, shouldn't you be either studying for exams or doing research for your dissertation?